# How can I assign same actions to multiple buttons at once?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, inheritance

I am working on a WinForms application where I want the user to click a button and then change the button's text (add +1 to the counter). I have multiple buttons and having three methods `Click` `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` for each of those would be pretty inefficient.

So I've set up a class, but don't know how to assign it to all the buttons.

```
public class AddButton : Button
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddButton ab = (AddButton)sender;

            Count++;
            ab.Text = Count + " Added";
        }
    }
```

Maybe I could also just link all the button's `EventHandlers` to one, but I don't know how to start there and where to put the code. Here is the Visual Studio project download [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f_YRsTF-jhQqXkYsxvOrqBiiZZcg4d_h) if you need it.

Comment: Have you tried to assign the handler in the constructor?

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla Where do i find the constructor?

Comment: These really are 3 questions. 1) Adding the same handler to multiple controls is done by pasting the handler name into the event field in the properties/events pane after selecting all the controls. - 2) But you can also hook up events in code like so: control.eventname += handlername. Do it in  a loop and you are set. - 3) Your class lacks a constructor. (At least one parameterless one is needed for the designer to be happy!) Add one like so `public AddButton() {}`; put it into your class! . Now you can hook up the click by< adding this into the curlies: `Click += Button_Click;`

Comment: When I now click on a button, nothing happens. How can I make it so that clicking a button executes the ´Button_Click´ in the AddButton class?

Comment: I did show you; but you didn't update your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this code:

```
public class AddButton:Button
{
  public int Count { get; set; } = 0;

  public AddButton()
  {
    // After it's painted, set its text to current Counter
    this.Paint += (s, e) => this.Text = Count.ToString();
    this.Click += (s, e) => this.Text = (++Count).ToString(); 
  }
}
```

In your project it's enough to change buttons initialization from:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
```

to

```
Button button1 = new AddButton();
// or
AddButton button1 = new AddButton();
```

Comment: Where do I find the initialization form? Is it the Form1.Designer.cs file?

Comment: Yes :) You can also set the cursor on the variable and see all references (after righclicking it or by Shift + F12) and then find where it gets crated.

Comment: Turczyn I got that to work nicely. Can I also assign a second function other than changing the text? I've tried ´this.Click += (s, e) => TotalCount.Text = addButton10.Count + AddButton11.Count´, but it says unavailable context. Should i ask a new question for this or keep it in the comments?

Comment: @hjknvcaesdbuihjase You should first search for solution, which might be already present on this site. In case you can not find the answer then post question.